# HTML Select default option overriden when ng-options is populated

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

```
<select ng-model="grade.students" ng-options="st as st.name for st in students">
          <option disabled selected value > -- Select a Student --</option>
</select>
```

I have a select dropdown in my code. The options are populated from a RESTful database call. When the results are retrieved from the DB, the value displayed in the dropdown is set to the first value in students.

How can I make the disabled value be the one that is displayed till the user actually clicks on the dropdown and selects one?

Comment: Why is it disabled?

Comment: Because its an instruction to the user. 

Once an option is selected, another DB call is made to retrieve the data for that student. That's why I want the user to have to select one, rather than the first value in students being selected automatically when it gets populated.

Comment: No need to disable it. Can set selected on a disabled option...makes no sense

Comment: I'm using `ng-change` to trigger the call to the database, so I don't want that call to be made with ` -- Select a Student --` as the value, that's why I want it to be disabled so that the user can not select it again.

Comment: So just make sure model has a value before making request. Don't try to reinvent the wheel

Comment: But then the user would be able to select that value, which would not work.

Comment: That's what validation is for and how `<select>` has been used for many years

Comment: just push() the default value onto the array of options before you assign it to scope. Be sure to set the ng-model vairable to the default value as well that way it is selected on render. Hope this helps.

Comment: @JustinHerter how would I set the default value?

Comment: @NishantRoy I posted an answer that should explain. Just let me know if you get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var student1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'cool guy'
}
var student2 = {
    id: 2,
    name: 'nerd'
}
var students = [student1, student2];
```

so I assume you have a function that returns students and then you assign the students to scope...?

before you assign students to scope push the default option onto the student array

```
$scope.selectedStudent = 0;
students.push({ id: 0, name: 'select one' });
$scope.students = students;
```

Then you will setup a function to call when a student is selected

```
$scope.someFunction = function (student) {
    // do something with the selected student
}
```

Now in your html you would have something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedStudent" ng-options="st.id as st.name for st in students" ng-change="someFunction(st)"></select>
```

if later on you decide to have a preselected student just set $scope.selectedStudent to the id of the student. and done.